# Splash screen does not show up when product export

Tags: eclipse, splash-screen, rcp

When i run my rcp application inside eclipse  the splash screen is showing as it should. But when i export the product splash screen does not show up even if it is a new rcp application where i did not change splash screen at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not added the location of the plugin which contained the splash screen...

> Product->Splash->Location->Plug-in

Comment: Glen Lamb, this is the proper way to do this. Remove all records you added by hand, then go to Product->Splash->Location->Plug-in and add your splash screen there. Clean, build, run and you are ready

Answer (score 8):

Ok, make sure/check for the following 
(these steps are always to be done for your app export target directory, **not** the eclipse IDE directory):

- Does the RCP Mail Template example work correctly? It should be perfectly possible to create the example app with the wizards and then export via the hyperlink in the first page of the manifest editor. This result should be always working. Otherwise check your eclipse installation.
- Did you use the correct launcher? There are eclipse.exe and eclipsec.exe (the latter is the command line version => no splash)
- The exported result must contain your bundle in jar or directory form (for our product both forms are working) under /plugins (the bundle itself logically needs to contain your splash.bmp in the root). If I remember correctly it needs to be a BMP with certain parameters. Find them by examining the RCP Mail Template example.

  - If not: check your product definition (included plugins/features)
- Try to use the RCP Mail Template example image for your app. Does it also fail to work? If so, try to open/save with Windows Paint.
- Next, make sure your "config.ini" in the configuration sub-folder has the following entry:
  osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/<your bundle without version appendix>
  (osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/<your bundle w/o version> also works
  I don't know if there are any defaults for this setting but maybe this time you should explicitly tell the launcher where to look for the splash image. :-)
- Make sure there is no -D parameter that overwrites the config.ini setting in the eclipse.ini next to the launcher (eclipse.exe)

  - is there a "noSplash" in eclipse.ini or config.ini?
- If your bundle is a jar, check if the bmp is correctly extracted somewhere under configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher...

  - If not: Then the image is not correctly included/found within the bundle jar. Check your build.properties
- Delete the workspace and start your rcp app with -clean
- Maybe start with -console -consoleLog and -noExit to recognize arising error messages during startup

Comment: The export wizard from the manifest creates a plugin but not an executable application from what I can see. Don't you need a product configuration to do that?

Comment: OK I don't have this folder: configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher

Comment: I still haven't managed to solve my problem but I have managed to work out that there is a problem with my specific BMP file. My application works with the Mail Templates splash.bmp, but wont work with the BMP i'm trying to use. I've re saved it with paint, and saved a new image with a scribble on from paint and they don't work either. But all work when running from inside eclipse.

Comment: maybe you should use another image processing tool like irfanview/gimp. Try to get to know the color depth/bitrate/etc. settings from the working image. Then try to save your image accordingly.

Comment: I was using gimp, it didn't work, I ended up changing my image to the same dimensions as the example, print screening my image, pasting it in to paint and saving that down. It now works, thank you for you pretty comprehensive debugging guide.

Answer (score 7):

Did you add the splash screen image to the build.properties file?

if not, the image is not part of your generated *.jar file

Example:

```
bin.includes = splash.bmp,\
               product.properties,\
               about.ini,\
               about.properties,\
               plugin_customization.ini,\
               META-INF/
```

Comment: yes i have added.. do i have to make my own config.ini to add the splash path maybe?

Comment: Running the application inside the workbench is more forgiving than as a stand alone app!

Comment: @DuncanKrebs which doesn't help when everything looks fine during testing and you deploy it and just have no clue why it's not working.

Answer (score 7):

In my case splash.bmp was 32-bit and it was not shown. After I converted it to 24-bit with GIMP, it was shown (Eclipse 3.7).

Comment: Not just 24-bit format but in GIMP I had to select 24-bit and under compatibility options select "Do not write color space information".  Then exe launcher could open the splash.

Comment: Using ImageMagick's "convert" that would fix it for me: "convert broken.bmp BMP2:splash.bmp" - this change was also necessary for Eclipse 4.3.2

Comment: +1 for 'Not just 24-bit format but in GIMP I had to select 24-bit and under compatibility options select "Do not write color space information".' 24-bit is not enough -- need to suppress the color space info too or splash won't load in Eclipse Neon (4.6.0) on Windows 10 64-bit. Because it's only 2016 - why should color space info be supported in WIndows? :|

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that your product dependencies (e.g. in the product editor, tab Dependencies) contains the plugin org.eclipse.ui.intro.  Also, you will have to add the extra org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal if your Welcome is based on the intro.universal.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late , but after following all above steps didn't resolved my problem.Trying below step resolved my problem.
In .prdocut file under Dependencies tab there is a check button "Include optional dependencies when 
computing required plug-ins" finally made my splash screen to be visible.
If any one is referring to this answer please make sure you follow above answers and try this answer.